# Migration from solrj to spring-data-solr

Tags: java, solr, solrj, spring-data-solr

Can't find full tutorial for spring-data-solr.

Have a question about migrating to `spring-data-solr`.

For example I have the following query on solarj:

```
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.setQuery("*:*");
query.setParam("df", region);
query.setParam("fq", addType(param));
query.setParam("fl", region);
query.setRows(10000);
query.addSort(region, SolrQuery.ORDER.asc);

query.set(GroupParams.GROUP, true);
query.set(GroupParams.GROUP_FIELD, groupField);
query.set(GroupParams.GROUP_MAIN, true);
query.set(GroupParams.GROUP_FORMAT, "simple");
SolrTemplate server = /*initialization*/
server.execute(client -> client.query(SOLR_COLLECTION_NAME, query));
```

So how can I migrate this code to spring-data-solr `Query` class? Or even to `SolrRepository` if possible? You might wanna ask me what I have tried so far: now I tried to create solar query as:

```
Query query = new SimpleQuery("*:*");
query.setRows(10000);
query.addSort(new Sort(Direction.ASC, SCHOOL_REGION));
```

But how can I set params like "df", "fl", etc. and all of the group params? I don't see setters for it.

And the second question is can I use `SolrCrudRepository` for complicated query like this?

Comment: This is from 3 years ago - I'm assuming you don't still need help. Looks like these days (and maybe 3 years ago) the Spring - Solr setup would have you create query methods using bean type naming conventions.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/4.0.10.RELEASE/reference/html/#solr.query-methods.criterions

The Product entity is returned, so my guess is that the fields in the entity would end up being automatically used in the `fl` values so the entities could be populated.

    List<Product> findByNameAndPopularity(String name, Integer popularity);

Comment: @LeeWallen what about df?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer may help somebody, so:

spring-data-solr (v4.0.10.RELEASE) does not support [DisMax Parameters](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-dismax-query-parser.html#TheDisMaxQueryParser-DisMaxParameters), so you're not able to use these params by default, the solution was to create custom SolrQuery:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class ExtendedQuery extends SimpleQuery {
    private List<String> queryFields;
    private String defaultField;
}
```

Then we can set these params like:

```
query.setDefaultField(SCHOOL_CITY);
query.setQueryFields(Arrays.asList("school_name^150.0", "school_city^30.0"));
```

One more thing you'll need is to create custom [QueryParser](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-solr/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/solr/core/QueryParser.html):

```
public class ExtendedQueryParser extends QueryParserBase<AbstractQueryDecorator> {

    private final DefaultQueryParser defaultQueryParser;

    public ExtendedQueryParser(MappingContext mappingContext) {
        super(mappingContext);
        defaultQueryParser = new DefaultQueryParser(mappingContext);
    }

    @Override
    public final SolrQuery doConstructSolrQuery(
            AbstractQueryDecorator query, Class<?> domainType) {
        ExtendedQuery decoratedQuery = (ExtendedQuery) query.getDecoratedQuery();

        SolrQuery solrQuery = 
            defaultQueryParser.constructSolrQuery(decoratedQuery, domainType);

        Optional.ofNullable(decoratedQuery.getDefaultField())
            .ifPresent(defaultField -> 
                solrQuery.setParam(CommonParams.DF, defaultField));
        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(decoratedQuery.getQueryFields())) {
            solrQuery.setParam(DisMaxParams.QF, 
                String.join(SPACE, decoratedQuery.getQueryFields()));
        }

        return solrQuery;
    }
}
```

The last step is to register this parser:

```
@Bean
public ExtendedQueryParser extendedQueryParser(SolrTemplate solrTemplate) {
    ExtendedQueryParser extendedQueryParser = new ExtendedQueryParser(null);
    solrTemplate.registerQueryParser(ExtendedQuery.class, extendedQueryParser);
    return extendedQueryParser;
}
```